# How to compute date for touch -t

Tags: command-line, time, touch-command

How to create date type in bash?

what this date mean?  '1803141400'

```
touch -t 1803141400 test1 test2
```

How can I compute time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [touch man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/touch.1.html):

```
  -t STAMP
              use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

where:

```
CC: First two digit of the year
YY: Last two digits of the year
MM: Month (two-digit numeric month)
DD: Day (two-digit numeric day i.e. day of month)
hh: Hour
mm: Minutes
ss: Seconds
```

`[]` indicates that field is optional

In your examples `1803141400` means: `2018 mar 14, 14.00` and `touch` will change time stamp of `test1` and `test2` files according to this value.

```
$ ls -l test1 test2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yourUser yourGroup 0 mar 14  2018 test1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yourUser yourGroup 0 mar 14  2018 test2
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `-t` options allow the user to add a specific last access time when you create a file using `touch` command .

It is followed by a string  in the date, month, year, minute:second format, and the latter uses a [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] format, where `CC`,`YY` and `SS` is optional.

For example, to create  file temp with time stamp

```
 [guru@guru-Aspire ~]$touch -t 12141105  temp
 [guru@guru-Aspire ~]$ls -l --full-time temp

  -rw-rw-r-- 1 guru guru 0 2014-12-14 11:05:00.000000000 +0530 temp
```

As you ca see if you do not provide `CC` and `YY`, it automatically insert the current CC and YY.

In your case i.e. `touch -t 1803141400 test1 test2`

it will create a timstamp of

year- 2018 (first pair of  digit)

month- 03 (second pair of digit)

date- 14  (third pair of digit)

time - 14:02 (fourth and fifth pair of digit)

```
[guru@guru-Aspire ~]$ ls -l --full-time test*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guru guru 0 2018-03-14 14:00:00.000000000 +0530 test1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 guru guru 0 2018-03-14 14:00:00.000000000 +0530 test2
```